# How do I use =if(countifs if a value of a cell matches another cell and not a specific value?

Tags: excel-formula

Not quite sure how to word this so I will give a quick example and the desired output.

if g2=1 and j2=n2 then the result should show "Healthy" if not then "Not Healthy"

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you just checking if the two cells match each other? If so, `=IF(G2=J2, "Healthy", "Unhealthy")`. To partial match (e.g. if G2 contains J2) then `=IF(COUNTIF(G2, "*" & J2 & "*")=1, "Healthy", "Unhealthy")`

Comment: It's not just if the 2 cells match each other, G2 must = 1 and then if j2 matches n2 Healthy not Healthy.

Comment: Use the "and" function to test this; =IF(AND(G2=1,J2=N2),"Healthy","Not Healthy")

Comment: @RetiredGeek, this is almost what I need however it is showing Not Healthy if both j2 and n2 are blank. Is there a way to ignore if both j and n are blank?

Comment: @irishombian, when I run it it shows healthy if J2 & N2 are blank. Are you sure those cells are blank? Try Clear Contents on them and see what you get.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I should mention that the values of j and n are produced by a vlookup. But regardless I would still need the blank values ignored. Only if they are both blank.

Comment: @irishombain, If they are both blank it would return Healthy. So whatever your VLookup is returning is not just a blank. I'd take a look at your lookup tables and see what is in those cells and clean that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if g2=1 and j2=n2 then the result should show "Healthy" if not then "Not Healthy"

is equivalent to :

```
=IF(AND(G2=1,J2=N2),"HEALTHY","NOT HEALTHY")
```

Please share if it works/not.